# Could not create directory /wp-content/upgrade/

Tags: errors, upgrade

When I try to automatically install updates to Wordpress or plugins, I receive an error:

> An error occurred while updating... Could not create directory
>   .../wp-content/upgrade/...

My web host runs an Apache environment, and other Wordpress websites I own don't have this problem.  I have CHMOD the /wp-content/upgrade folder to both 777 and 2777, without any change in the error message.

I have installed the Core Control plugin, and the Filesystem Access module says the only error is that SSH2 is not available, but this is not required for automatic updates.

How do I perform the command:

```
chown www-data:www-data /path/to/wp-content/ -R
```

from a Windows machine?  Is it telnet, or putty?  What commands do I use to login?  Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try FTP? I'd recommend Filezilla in this case.

Comment: @CiprianPopescu have already tried this.  Mentioned in 2nd paragraph of Q.  Thx.

Comment: I was out of disk space. Increasing the quota solved my problem.

Answer (score 17):

> **First do not use 777, change it back to 755.**

Second you need to add the proper group permissions most likely to the same that Apache is running under.
To find that out try:

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

You will see the Apache user group on the left.

Now change your WordPress folder to the same user group, you can do this in a parent folder or sub folder but for sanity it usually best for parent folder, use `-R` to recursively do it.

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/wp-root-folder
```

- To login on windows use [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/)
- Enter your hostname and port
- Choose connection type depending on server settings
- Click open

If you try to chown and get denied you will need root privileges , type `sudo su` and your password.

ps. It would help if you mentioned what OS your server is running and if your running a php permission script like suPHP.

Comment: Unfortunately the host is not accepting any connections of any kind from Putty.  The server is Apache, and I am not running any special permission scripts myself.

Comment: If the host does not give you command line access, then they must fix it themselves. The web server is Apache but it is still running on an operating system, like Ubuntu, Fedora, etc. For good measure before you ask your host disable all your plugins and activate the default theme.

Comment: The web hosts confirmed the permission for Wordpress on the site in question completely match those of another Wordpress installation on another site of mine, both running the same version of WP.

Comment: I was having this problem for days and was surprised that this step wasn't clarified by http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions or other documentation on the web. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the note on `ps aux | grep apache` -- turns out my server is not running with the user I thought it was! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `vsftpd` as your FTP server and have enabled passive connections, you need to add `pasv_promiscuous=YES` to `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`.