# can't update plugins or wordpress or install new plugins

Tags: html

how to update plugins wordpress how to replace my code in new plugins ??
I have some plugins that need to be updated (as well as WordPress) and I have tried the automatic update button and the update fails. I get an error message "Could not create directory.: /public_html/wp-content/upgrade." I have tried to delete the upgrade folder in cPanel and then create a new one but it won't let me create a new .php file.

Comment: This is not a WordPress issue. I suggest you contact your server provider to ask them what would be the best steps to take or read here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/23569/45047

Answer (score 0):

Some plugins require the /wp-content/ folder be made writeable, but in such cases they will let you know during installation. In some cases, this may require assigning 755 permissions. If you are on the shared hosting they always uses the "suexec" and above case will not apply for them. If your hosting use the "suexec" approach for running PHP binaries which is a popular approach used by many web hosts

In such cases an "suexec" configuration, the correct permissions scheme is simple to understand.

- All directories should be 755 or 750.
- All files should be 644 or 640. Exception: wp-config.php should be
  440 or 400 to prevent other users on the server from reading it.
- No directories should ever be given 777, even upload directories.
  Since the php process is running as the owner of the files, it gets
  the owners permissions and can write to even a 755 directory.

Use FTP and and connect to your hosting and Update the Files permissions as mentioned in https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Follow this guide it's very simple to follow. I had the same problem and as i follow the guide it actually solved my problem.